# Ubuntu 19.04 upgrade error: /usr/lib/python3.7/html/__pycache__': Permission denied

Tags: permissions, updates, python, 19.04

I made upgrade to Ubuntu - from 18.10 to 19.04.
Now I got an error after logging:

```
Error found when loading /etc/profile:
find: '/usr/lib/python3.7/html/__pycache__': Permission denied 
find: '/usr/lib/python3.7/xml/etree/__pycache__': Permission denied
```

I have read on another topic to run:

```
cat /etc/profile
```

Output I got is:

```
# /etc/profile: system-wide .profile file for the Bourne shell (sh(1))
# and Bourne compatible shells (bash(1), ksh(1), ash(1), ...).
if [ "${PS1-}" ]; then
if [ "${BASH-}" ] && [ "$BASH" != "/bin/sh" ]; then
# The file bash.bashrc already sets the default PS1.
# PS1='\h:\w\$ '
if [ -f /etc/bash.bashrc ]; then
  . /etc/bash.bashrc
fi
else
if [ "`id -u`" -eq 0 ]; then
  PS1='# '
else
  PS1='$ '
fi
fi
fi

if [ -d /etc/profile.d ]; then
for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh; do
if [ -r $i ]; then
  . $i
fi
done
unset i
fi
```

Any idea?

Comment: Can you execute ls -l /usr/lib/python3.7/ and give the result ?

Comment: Yes, but it is too long so I made .txt file. Here is the link: https://bit.ly/354Cngy

Comment: drwxr-xr-x 3 root root   4096 lis   1 12:17 htm //

drwxr-xr-x 7 root root   4096 lis   1 12:17 xml // If there is problem with permisions, what permision should I put?

Comment: For both folders ("html" folder and "xml/etree" folder) I got same results -> 
drwxr----- 2 root root  4096 lis   1 13:11 __pycache__  ->

If there is a problem with permissions, what permission should I put?